# Reducing the size of title and author

Tags: fontsize, gap

Below you see the code of the tex file. I would like to make the following changes:

1. How to change the size of author and title?
2. You see there is a gap between the title and the top of the first page. I am wondering how to reduce this gap?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[draft]{pgf}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[margin=1.2in, centering]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}   
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym,mathtools}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{exer}{exercise}[subsection]
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ques}{Question}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{ex}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{problem}[thm]{Problem}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{nota}{Notation}
\newtheorem*{acknowledgement}{Acknowledgements}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
\usepackage{subfig}

%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
%\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linktocpage}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{qqttcc}{rgb}{0.,0.2,0.8}
    \title{ABC}
    \author{John Doe}
    
    \date{\today}

    \keywords{}
    \maketitle


I like math!


\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You seem to be asking three questions rather than one. Please edit to ask a single question and ask further questions if appropriate. Please also retag: this has nothing to do with Overleaf.

Comment: @cfr, I removed the first one and left the second and third one because they are kind of related.

Comment: That seems reasonable, indeed. Thanks for editing.

Comment: The AMS classes are primarily aimed at people preparing articles etc. for publication by AMS. In that case, you should not change the sizing of fonts or dimensions etc. While it is obviously possible to redefine things, are you sure this makes sense? Classes designed with particular publications in mind are not designed to make user modification easy. They're designed to ensure conformity with a particular publication's format.

Comment: @cfr, actually I want to use this template to write a teaching statement that is why I want to change size of title and author. Or maybe you have some other suggestion?

Comment: If you used `article`, for example, you could use `geometry` and `titling`, say. You could try those with `amsart`, but you might get oddness. It really depends if you need aspects of the AMS class. If not, customising a standard class is probably simpler.

Comment: @cfr, I am wondering how to change the size of author and title?

Comment: Best wait for advice from somebody who currently uses AMS classes. I've only used a modified version of `amsbook` a long time ago.

Comment: @RFZ, please: a) remove all packages NOT needed for this problem, b) use the titlepage environment to layout your own titlepage, see e.g. https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_5)%3A_Customising_Your_Title_Page_and_Abstract